# How to keep code running whitin a script

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I have a simple script which displays current memory usage, disk usage, and CPU load within a terminal. Here is the code so you can see what I mean:

```
free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf " | Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%%)|\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2 }'

df -h | awk '$NF=="/"{printf " | Disk Usage: %d/%dGB (%s) |\n", $3,$2,$5}'

top -bn1 | grep load | awk '{printf " | CPU Load: %.2f |\n", $(NF-2)}'
```

The problem is that it only runs that code within the script 1 time. I need to automatically keep running that script every 1 second without having to keep reloading the script. So basically I just want it in some sort of continuous loop while the script can do other stuff.

The reason I want it to continue to refresh every 1 second, is because it only shows the CPU usage 1 time right when you run the script, but CPU changes frequently, so I need it to keep displaying current data.

Comment: You can use the `watch` command to run your script.   `watch -n1 /path/to/script`

Comment: You might also want to consider parsing `/proc/loadavg` instead of calling top to get the load average, as that will be much more efficient.

Comment: Didn't we do this just a couple of days ago?

Comment: @Jesse_b That does what I need it to, but it uses the entire terminal and waits until I press ^C to exit it. Is there anyway I can make this run within a script that does other stuff as well?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the while loop :

```
while :
do
    free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf " | Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%%)|\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2 }'
    df -h | awk '$NF=="/"{printf " | Disk Usage: %d/%dGB (%s) |\n", $3,$2,$5}'   
    top -bn1 | grep load | awk '{printf " | CPU Load: %.2f |\n",$(NF-2)}'  
    sleep 1
done
```

: is a built-in command that always return true

if you prefer something more readable you can use true :

```
while true
do
    free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf " | Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%%)|\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2 }'
    df -h | awk '$NF=="/"{printf " | Disk Usage: %d/%dGB (%s) |\n", $3,$2,$5}'   
    top -bn1 | grep load | awk '{printf " | CPU Load: %.2f |\n",$(NF-2)}'  
    sleep 1
done
```

you can get more information about the difference between ":" and "true" there :
[What is the purpose of the : (colon) GNU Bash builtin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin)

If you want a clean display of information you can add the clear function at the beginning of the loop such as :

```
while :
do
    clear
    free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf " | Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%%)|\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2 }'
    df -h | awk '$NF=="/"{printf " | Disk Usage: %d/%dGB (%s) |\n", $3,$2,$5}'   
    top -bn1 | grep load | awk '{printf " | CPU Load: %.2f |\n",$(NF-2)}'  
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: If you run the code you can see what it really does and see what I need to update every 1 sec. Running the code you provided creates a list of outputs below the initial one, and I just want it to stay where it is while updating just the output of your CPU, etc.

Comment: @iamr00t I guess you can add a clear at the beginning of the loop

Comment: That sort of works, but it clears the enitre script, so how can I make just that part refresh within a script while there is other stuff going on in the script. So the CPU/Storage part would be on top...and there would be other stuff below it. But the stuff below I want to stay still and not refresh with the part above it. The code you suggested makes the whole script clear every 1 sec.

Comment: just use watch as @Jesse_b proposed